# split string based on special characters in python

Tags: python, string, split, ascii

For example the string is `hello %$ world %^& let me ^@ love && you`   the expected result would be hello in one variable and rest in other variables example a="hello" b="world" etc.

Comment: Use regular expresson for these problems..

Comment: Look at `re.split`, split on any non-word sequences (or whatever your criterion is). And you certainly don't want to end up with separate *variables*, you'll want all those values in a list or dict.

Comment: it should be in separate variables @deceze

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/476 – *variable variables* are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression

**Like this:-**

```
import re
a = "hello %$ world %^& let me ^@ love && you"
print(re.findall(r'\w+',a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user ([regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to retrieve worlds from the string):

```
import re
my_string = "hello %$ world %^& let me ^@ love && you"
re.findall(r'\w+\b', my_string)
# ['hello', 'world', 'let', 'me', 'love', 'you']
```

Please see more about regular expressions in [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

## Update

As asked in comments, attaching regexp to retrieve group of words separated by special characters:

```
my_string = "hello world #$$ i love you #$@^ welcome to world"
re.findall(r'(\w+[\s\w]*)\b', my_string)  
# ['hello world', 'i love you', 'welcome to world']
```

Comment: i know this but how to store string after a special character for example `hello world #$$ i love you #$@^ welcome to world` output must be a="hello world" b="i love you" c="welcome to world"

Comment: or what if to import a csv file which has something like this in a column and save each output to a particular column !

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer would be a regexp. I would recommend looking in to tokenizer from NLTK, they encompas research on the topic and give you the flexibility to switch to something more sophisticated later on. Guess what? It offers a Regexp based tokenizer too!

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer 

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)')
corpus = tokenizer.tokenize("hello %$ world %^& let me ^@ love && you")
```

Comment: As per the update it would be : tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'([A-Za-z0-9 ]+)')